# Connect to broadband connected laptop wirelessly

Tags: networking, wifi

I have one laptop that is connected to broadband internet connection via a modem provided by the service provider.

i have another laptop and i want to connect it to the internet also via networking but using wireless technology. i don't want to spend on any wireless hubs or switches so is it possible to do it via bluetooth or transmit wireless signals using the internal wireless hardware. The current laptop that has the internet connects to the modem with a cat5e cable.

The laptops are an IBM Thinkpad T42  and a Dell Inspiron 1525, the IBM thinkpad connects to the modem and i want to connect the Inspiron to the internet using wireless technology.

Both the laptops are running Windows XP Service pack 2

Comment: What OS are they each running?

Comment: both run Window XP service pack 2

Comment: What did i get the - vote for the question it was a genuine question and i even got an answer to it, whoever down voted please tell me what was the problem with the question?

Comment: -1: No offense, but this is obviously *not* by or for "a system administrator or IT professional". When SF goes live, it'll be tough enough to keep the "unwashed masses" (aka lusers, aka home users) from overrunning the place - got to set the tone early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Control Panel>Network Connections
Pick the wired connection you wish to share, right click, select 'Properties'.
Go to the advanced tab and select "Allow other users to connect through this computer's internet connection."
Click ok.

Now go to the wireless connection and create an ad-hoc network for your wireless clients to connect to. ([See here.](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx))

Hope this helped XD

Comment: i almost gave up and thought that this thing didn't work till i read the part that you need to share the wired connection, thanks a lot it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to investigate an ad hoc wireless network.  Here is an article on how to set up an Ad Hoc network with XP: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/setup/adhoc.mspx. If you are using Vista or Win7 the steps should be similar.  I had done this before in a group of condos where only 1 had broadband and others wanted to share it.

Comment: Seems like what i am looking for ill try to configure it and get back to you if it works sucessfully

Comment: I think you will be pleased.  I bring two laptops with me when i travel and I had to leave one in a friends condo to be my wireless AP, it worked well.  It was actually a little Dell Mini 9, and the performance was just fine.